# Unknown coefficients for 2nd order linear ODE - where did I go wrong?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve a 2nd order linear ODE today with the guide of my lecture notes, and I started going ahead of the steps of the lecture to see if I could do it myself. I'm concerning myself with the following ordinary differential equation:

$$y''+6y'+5y = 13\cos x$$

So, once I found the complimentary function I turned my sights to the particular integral of $13\cos x$.
However, the lecture notes decided to use the form $a\sin x + b\cos x$ while I instead chose $a\cos x + b\sin x$. Since the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, I figured it wouldn't matter which one was applied to which function. However, they ended up getting the following solution:

$$y_{PI} = \frac {3}{2}\sin x + cos\ x$$

While mine was:

$$y_{PI} = \frac {3}{2}\cos x + sin\ x$$

Clearly my answer is wrong, otherwise it would be the exact same as theirs, but I don't see what logical gap I made in my thought processes. If I have to solve for the unknown coefficients as $a\sin x + b\cos x$ instead of my way, why is that? If there is nothing wrong, at least I know I must have made a calculation error.

Comment: I assume you took "asinx+bcosx" like as "acosx+bsinx".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. @TakahiroWaki

Answer (score 2):

$$y= a \cos x + b \sin x$$
$$y' = - a \sin x + b \cos x = b \cos x - a \sin x$$
$$y"=-a\cos x -b \sin x$$

$$y"+6y'+5y = (-a+6b+5a) \cos x + (-b-6a+5b) \sin x$$

Hence

$$4a+6b = 13$$
$$-6a+4b= 0$$

We can see that $(a,b)=( 1, \frac32)$ is a solution and $( \frac32, 1)$ is not a solution.

Your teacher is right.

We can't comment much as we are not shown your working, but you are right that $a$ and $b$ are just arbitrary constant.

Comment: I see. So I must've made a maths error then, and my postulate at the beginning is plausible?

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, in fact, you should be able to follow your teacher's working, just swap $a$ and $b$.